# Markdown syntax highlighting not working as expected

Tags: javascript, markdown, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3 I am using the package `Markdown Extended` and `Markdown Preview` to build the Markdown documents I write.

I am trying to get nicely formatted JavaScript code, however, for some reason it isn't being built and displayed correctly.

In Sublime, the code is highlighted and looks great, but when I build it and view it in my browser I just see an in-line typical grey piece of code, with `javascript` still at the front of it.

Below is an example of what I am talking about:

**Example Markdown code**

````
```javascript
var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
alert(s);
```
````

**Output**

```
<code>
::before
javascript var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting"; alert(s);
::after
</code>
```

**MarkdownPreview user settings**

```
{
"github_mode": "gfm",
"guess_language": false,
"enabled_extensions": ["codehilite(guess_lang=False,pygments_style=github)"],
"enable_highlight": true
}
```

Comment: I don't see any HTML in that output. Are you sure you're using the right conversion target? What do you have set up for markdown configuration, and what do you do to effect the conversion?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans just added the actual HTML to the question, along with my `user settings` for `MarkdownPreview`.

Comment: installed it, pasted your code, built it; removing the `javascript` from the block makes it work fine. I don't see anything in the README.md that indicates adding a language indicator to a triple backtick should work, so... works as intended?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
It is supposed to have syntax-specific highlighting built-in. Me doing a re-install and setting these settings: `{
    "github_mode": "gfm",
    "parser": "github",
    "build_action": "browser",
    "enabled_extensions": [
        "extra",
        "github",
        "codehilite(guess_lang=False,pygments_style=github)"
    ]
}` got it working.

Comment: handy - worth putting those settings in your own, answer too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a fresh install of Markdown Preview and a restart of Sublime...

Here are the settings:

```
{ "github_mode": "gfm", "parser": "github",     "build_action": "browser", "enabled_extensions": [ "extra", "github", "codehilite(guess_lang=False,pygments_style=github)" ] }
```